# Any Good iOSOpenDev Sample Code/Reference Materials?

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, cydia, tweak

I've had some experience developing iOS apps and I'm currently working on an idea I had for a Cydia tweak. The tweak would work with action menus, adding a new button to the menu and presenting an interface when the button is tapped on.

I'm trying to do this with the action menu template on iOSOpenDev. I currently have iOSOpenDev installed and have created a new project using the action menu template. However, I don't know how to proceed after this.

I'm looking for some sample code or reference materials on how to create tweaks using iOSOpenDev, but so far I haven't even found one sample project. Is there good up-to-date documentation or tutorials on how to use iOSOpenDev to create Cydia tweaks?

Comment: After several more hours of searching, I still haven't seen anything that gives the slightest clue on how to actually create something using iOSOpenDev. All I've found are tons of news websites reporting on the existence of iOSOpenDev. I will continue to search, but if anyone could link me to a tutorial, or perhaps write one up, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code:

- [Mobile Substrate tutorial on iPodTouchFans](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-hooking-springboard.103558/)
- [MobileSubstrate reference and examples on the iPhone Development Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate)

And here's what you have to do after having written all the code:

1. I don't use iOSOpenDev, but if I recall correctly, it packages your tweak into a Debian package file. If this is the case, you simply copy that file to your device, install it (perhaps using `dpkg -i <filename.deb>`, and restart SpringBoard.
2. If not, then you just grab the resulting `.dylib` and `.plist` files, and copy them over to the device to the `/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries` directory, and once again, you respring.